# Simple all in one mod_rewrite for static prototyping

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, static

I will provide a little background of my problem. I'm working on a static HTML5/CSS3 prototype for a PHP CMS. One of the things I want to is to have clean URLs. I had stuff like this at the start:

`localhost:8888/file.php`

And wanted it to:

`localhost:8888/file` or without the trail slash `localhost:8888/file`

I did a quick search on Stackoverflow and found several results over the matter and I kindly used this one to do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```

The problem with this approach is when i want to set deep levels on my CMS structure, like site/posts. Without mod_rewrite I need to create folders and create intense changes over the code to make things work like ../images/ to ../../images/ and so on, so boo to that solution. I need to go with mod_rewrite to make it work.

In addition, that mod_rewrite chunk of code doesn't work either with the folder stuff so I started a search in here to find a solution so I can do `/level1_level2_levelx.php` to `/level1/level2/level3/` or `/level1/level2/level3`. I did search in many ways but i don't find the correct answer to this.

Thank you all,

PD: I'm using MAMP.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking. Could you please add some examples in a `original => result` fashion? For example, `/file.php => /file`, `dir1/file.php => dir1/file`. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: `/level1_level2_levelx.php` => `/level1/level2/level3/`

Comment: Right now, I'm using `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /$1_$2` to do this, but the problem I found is, it doesn't recognize my other folders, it gives conflicts /css/main.css or css/main.css, I probably will need a rule to point any css/ image/ to a certain url.

Comment: I see. I believe that what you want to do is fairly complex (if at all possible). The simple (and usually sane) way of doing this would be to have a proper directory structure, such as `/level1/level2/level3.php`, and just strip the `.php` from the end with mod_rewrite. That is much easier to manage, and is what is normally done. Sorry I cannot help more :-(

Answer (score 0):

On the Rewrite front I'm guessing the the following should do what you ask:

Internally rewrite  entered URL:

```
  http://localhost:8888/file  
  OR:
  http://localhost:8888/file/
```

**to:**

```
  http://localhost:8888/file.php
```

**Rule:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/?$
RewriteCond %1\.php             -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  $1.php  [L]
```

But sound like you really want a custom 404 handler configured in Apache e.g.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "File not found."
</FilesMatch>

<Files favicon.ico>
    ErrorDocument 404 "-"
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /404-handler-script.php
```

And an associated **404-handler-script.php** added to do whatever mapping you want internally e.g.

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/4

Note: This script redirects the browser to the destinations script rather than serve it itself.